# how to install windows 7 on emachines

Tags: windows-7, emachines

Is it possible to install windows on emachines?
I'm trying to press f2 on the keyboard so that I could see some setup but the default emachine interface always shows up. I'm just new to emachines, how do I do it?How to get to the bios menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get into the bios screen try delete instead of f2.  They are both listed on here: http://michaelstevenstech.com/bios_manufacturer.htm

A big list of manufacturers with bios shortcuts.